# $_FILES[“image”][“tmp_name”] is empy with no data

Tags: php

I have written the following code. But I am getting empty `$_FILES[“image”][“tmp_name”]` with no value.

Php:

```
if ($_FILES) {
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo("img/" . basename($_FILES["Image"]["name"]), PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

$target_file = "img/" . uniqid(rand()) . ".$imageFileType";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
   $pic = $target_file;    
} else {

    echo "Invalid File";
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<form action="product-add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="products-form">
            <p> Image:</p> <input type="file" name="Image" >   
            <input type="submit" value="ADD PRODUCT" class="btn">
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Add a `print_r($_FILES);` to the top of the code and resubmit. Show us that array.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears to me this is not right:

```
$target_file = "img/" . uniqid(rand()) . ".$imageFileType";
```

it should be

```
$target_file = "img/" . uniqid(rand()) . "." .$imageFileType;
```